# How to find len with with in list statement

Tags: python, list

```
user_info =[["cinthis kakk", 98110], ["jorge nene"], ["Alac bladwin", 94101], ["silver stone", 11201]]
```

I want to see count list with in list , for above example [2,1,2,2]
since jorge nene is only one it has to display 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply map the list with `len`:

```
list(map(len,user_info))
# [2, 1, 2, 2]
```